# Wordpress search box is a link?

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

For some reason when I click in the search box it acts like a link to a posts comments section. I know that is kind of vague but I really have no idea what other info I can give about the problem. The website is [lbk.newcoastmedia.com/wordpress](http://lbk.newcoastmedia.com/wordpress) and the search box is in the sidebar on the right side. Also, here is the code for my search form:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>" id="searchform" method="get">
    <div>
        <h3 class="search_title">search</h3>
        <label for="s" class="screen-reader-text"></label>
        <input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchsubmit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks for any help and if I need to include any other code let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advertisement above your search form has an unclosed `<a>` tag.  I'd suggest using [an HTML validation service](http://validator.w3.org/), as it will make suggestions and point out errors in markup.